# Moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, top-7, moderators

Robert Cartaino [recently announced the following on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/is-there-a-time-when-we-elect-non-temporary-moderators-on-an-se-2-0-site/69361#69361):

> The nominations for moderator elections will start about 30 days after a site graduates from beta.
>
> Moderator nominations will *not* be conducted as a meta thread, as they were done with the original sites. We are in the process of creating a custom software module for holding the Moderator nominations. It was the only way to conduct a fair and impartial nomination process, without the quirks of trying to force it into a meta-voting thread.
>
> We *just* passed 30 days on our first sites. The development is underway so we will start the first round of nominations as soon as the module is ready.

In light of this news (and a double check with Robert), this thread is being closed as no longer relevant.

---

**Some guidelines:**

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- The top voted nominations can go forward to the vote.
- The voting will be done on a separate question.

**The candidate:**

- Must be a currently registered user in good standing
- Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

Attribution goes to Jeff and ChrisF

More information on how this process will work [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) (meta.so) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) (blog).

Comment: Is this official? Are we really doing this already?

Comment: I don't know if this SE has been up long enough to nominate anyone outside of the standard favorites.

Comment: Shouldn't this be CW? Unless we want the nominators to be getting the reputation instead of the nominees. That, and it is kind of a community process that we'd be doing. It seems more fitting.

Comment: How do we define "reasonably high rep" for a site that's been online, what, 24 hours? Also, can we self-nominate?

Comment: Shouldn't we wait until the beta is at least public before we start nominations? There is a fairly limited pool, unless we're just going to go with the standard favorites, as Noctrine has said.

Comment: @Grace Note, I don't believe you receive reputation for Meta SE sites. But I agree, the CW designation does seem more fitting.

Comment: @Noctrine We don't know whether that is just for the Beta Phase, or will be the case for the real site. It's not that I'm worried about rep inflation or anything. But the whole nominator/nominee bit is what seems off if it isn't CW.

Comment: @Grace, I don't think it's just for the beta, I think it's the new model, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0/56191#56191

Comment: @Juan Y'know, for not having reputation on the Meta site, it's exceptionally awkward to earn the Mortarboard badge...

Comment: @Grace, I believe you *have* the reputation, check out your reputation tab (http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/reputation_gaming.png (first screenshot with FHC on gaming.meta)). It's just that that number is not valid, and the valid reputation is the number from the parent site. I'm not saying I like or dislike this system, but that's the way it seems to be.

Comment: @Juan Mmm. Still awkward. I'm neutral to the system, as well. We'll see how it plays out, though.

Comment: Meeh, I don't mind if this question stays empty until next week, but it will have to be done anyway

Comment: @C. Ross - what's the "top-7" tag for?

Comment: @ChrisF it's for Robert's blog post about Top 7 Meta.SE site questions

Comment: I think we should definitely decide on moderators before tomorrow, seeing as a public beta will need moderation.

Comment: @Arda, perhaps we need to ask that as a new question for the team to answer

Comment: @Arda, the moderators for the Web Applications site haven't been chosen yet and that's in public beta. The reputation thresholds were tweaked to allow the higher rep users to carry on "moderating".

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't realise that. If that's going to happen here, there's no real need yet.

Comment: @chris, that's true but web apps was the only one in public beta.. We'll have to see if the team can handle 4 in a few days

Answer (score 31):

I nominate [**Juan Manuel**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14/juan-manuel). Since he was the person who started the proposal, it seems like he should be accountable :P

That and he is one of the more active users.

Comment: Thanks! I would *love* to be a moderator; although I think it's a little early for nominations, I would gladly accept given the opportunity.

Comment: (I must confess this was a desire of mine since I learn a site like this could exist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy/42391#42391)

Comment: I vote for him too, he seems very involved in this proposal, since the beginning.

Comment: Of course you got my vote too, good job until now.

Comment: More than his involvement which is obvious, I agree with his "vision" of the site. Of what should be or not on it. And that's the essential point for a moderator at the beginning of the site. (And believe me, you will need **strong** convictions, because people will whine. A lot.)

Answer (score 22):

If there will be more than 1 moderator (because [I'd really love it to be me](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/moderator-nominations/215#215) if there can be only one, and I'd prefer not to have to battle to the death for the position) I also nominate [**Grace Note**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/85/grace-note).

He's very active on meta and he has very good ideas.

Comment: I accept this nomination on the same terms - only if there's going to be more than 1 moderator.

Comment: I was just about to do this, after Grace mentioned our slacking.

Comment: I know that I have disagreed with her in the past, however I think there are few people on gaming.SE or here in meta who have the best interests of the site at heart. I think she has done an excellent job at answering the question of "what is appropriate," and I would throw my support behind her.

Answer (score 7):

[**Oak**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122/oak)

Answer (score 7):

I nominate **[badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp)**

Extremely active in meta, chat, and on the parent site.  He has even fought battles for us on other meta sites.

Comment: Yesterday I was merely joking and not asking for somebody to nominate me :) That said, if you voted me I'd take it, but please be aware I don't really fit under "Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments."

Comment: @badp I didn't take it as you asking to be nominated.  I was just reminded that I meant to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I nominate [**Arda Xi**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56/arda-xi). He is very active, and was the highest repped user on the site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept, but on the same terms as Grace Note.

Comment: By the way, I don't mind being downvoted, but I'd like to hear why you downvote me. :-)

Comment: Aww. They edited out my joke :(

Answer (score 6):

I would like to throw my proverbial hat into the ring and self-nominate (**[FallenAngelEyes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/160/fallenangeleyes)**).  I committed to the site on Area 51 and have since been active in both closed and open beta, as well as having been involved in the GSE blog as editor. I do my best to post constructive and helpful answers, as well as comments, and I try to be active in discussions about site policies and community policing.

I hope the community will consider me. :) I'd appreciate it if you'd please let me know what areas I should improve in if you feel I am not suited for the job.

Comment: I always wanted to ask you at some point if you would mind being nominated. Guess I don't have to anymore ♪ You've got my full support. Always on top of policy changes, active and engaging with the community to find resolutions, a candidate who has the spirit and life of the site in heart. Plus, being a language expert is a plus.

Comment: @Grace Note: Thanks so much for the support and kind words, it means a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It seems very premature to me, but I'm going to go out on a limb and self-nominate ([**John Rudy**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/58/john-rudy)) anyway. You can check my Meta.SO history for examples of how I'd moderate, and what I would consider to be my respectful treatment of other members. (OK, there are probably a few snarky remarks to one specific user -- other Meta.SO members will recognize that immediately, but I could easily tone that down.)

> I'm leaving this here in case others would still wish to vote for me, but I would like to note that Juan Manuel and Grace Note have my full support. If it can't be me (grin) then I definitely want it to be one (or both) of them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to nominate [**ChrisF**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/chrisf).  He knows the SE system well, as he's a 10k user on *three* sites (SO, MSO, and SU).  He's participated in both the main site and here on meta.  He of course has to accept my nomination ...

Comment: I'll accept the nomination (only just noticed it, sorry).

Comment: @ChrisF You always do this to me.