# Are we going to have more legitimate moderator nominations/votes now that we're out of beta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

I think the current moderators have done a wonderful job so far, so this is more out of curiosity than it is out of a dire need for change.

Are we going to have some more formalized sort of moderator choosing, or are we just sticking with Grace Note, Juan Manuel, and Oak?

Comment: If I don't get re-elected, the last thing I'll do is ban everybody who didn't vote for me.

Comment: This comment is especially appropriate coming from the "godfather" of gaming.se.  Make us an offer we can't refuse!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The 2011 Community Moderator elections have begun. Well, they begun a day and a half ago, but that's not important!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/2011-community-moderator-election) [Go participate, while you still can!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election)

---

Robert Cartaino [recently announced the following on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/is-there-a-time-when-we-elect-non-temporary-moderators-on-an-se-2-0-site/69361#69361):

> The nominations for moderator elections will start about 30 days after a site graduates from beta.
>
> Moderator nominations will *not* be conducted as a meta thread, as they were done with the original sites. We are in the process of creating a custom software module for holding the Moderator nominations. It was the only way to conduct a fair and impartial nomination process, without the quirks of trying to force it into a meta-voting thread.
>
> We *just* passed 30 days on our first sites. The development is underway so we will start the first round of nominations as soon as the module is ready.

<s>There is going to be an official, community-run election at some point soon. An official date hasn't been presented yet; candidates will be drawn from our [nominations thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/moderator-nominations)! If you think someone is a promising candidate, make sure they're on that list and nominate them if they aren't.</s>

The three of us will continue to be your representatives until the elections are over. When the elections are over, whoever is elected will be the new moderators and our pro-tempore terms will end.

Comment: The nominations thread feels a little dated.  Would it be appropriate to start a new one?

Comment: @tzenes I've gone through it a few times now, and while I'm not much a fan of having people repeat themselves, there really isn't all *that* much even within the comments there. So we probably aren't served that much trouble to just re-create it. But I wouldn't suggest doing it *immediately*. I would like to pop Robert a call first and just check if that's alright.

Comment: I think there will be a different way to nominate users, I don't remember where I read it, but Robert was the author

Comment: That should read either "We three" or "The three of us", not "Us three". -- *Your friendly neighborhood English.SE user*

Comment: @mmyers Thanks! I'dn't've noticed that if it were not for you. ♪