# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Why no system message on the main site?

Comment: [I see one](http://i.imgur.com/4NFd3.png), @badp.

Comment: @Grace Much better than the automated, soulless one.

Comment: @badp those bytes were hand-crafted, you monster!

Comment: OMG, the community user speaks!!

Comment: Could anyone please tell me if the "community moderator" is different from the "moderator"? Sorry for the bother. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 118 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 118 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Gaming Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|Ivo      |Grace    |C. Ross  |Kevin Y  |Juan     |badp     |Fallen
  |Flipse   |Note     |         |         |Manuel   |         |AngelEyes   
  |---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
  |Fabian   |Arda Ξ   |Powerlord|Exhausted|Surplus  |Threshold
  |         |         |         |         |         |         
========================================================================
 1| 3.000000|65.000000| 5.000000| 0.000000|10.000000|25.000000| 3.000000
  | 2.000000| 3.000000| 2.000000| 0.000000|35.499999|29.500001
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Grace Note has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.
========================================================================
 2| 6.823071|29.500055| 6.092306| 0.546153|19.284601|38.653825| 4.092306
  | 3.638459| 4.638459| 2.000000| 2.730765|10.519262|28.817309
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.453847. Candidate
  | badp has reached the threshold and is elected.
========================================================================
 3| 7.859349|30.284031| 6.538280| 1.207266|22.577065|29.013071| 5.217725
  | 4.603890| 5.491069| 2.424968| 2.783286| 1.688744|28.804179
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.443344 and badp,
  | 0.745523.
========================================================================
 4| 8.059444|28.833623| 6.607456| 1.248280|23.084196|29.205075| 5.318116
  | 4.705464| 5.595892| 2.450816| 2.891638| 0.484516|28.777091
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.421680 and badp,
  | 0.740156.
========================================================================
 5| 8.059444|29.052765| 7.607456|         |23.662516|29.945231| 5.318116
  | 4.705464| 5.595892|         | 4.053116| 2.024552|28.486722
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Kevin Y and Powerlord and transferring
  | votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 6| 8.269393|28.710345| 7.693723|         |24.293258|28.631366| 5.510269
  | 4.872044| 5.749702|         | 4.269900| 0.476659|28.432526
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.413465 and badp,
  | 0.704107.
========================================================================
 7| 8.855928|29.123810| 7.693723|         |26.175686|29.044350| 5.510269
  |         | 5.749702|         | 5.846532| 2.091424|28.038368
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Fabian and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
========================================================================
 8| 9.099782|28.184036| 7.782258|         |26.864886|28.310707| 5.680908
  |         | 5.897272|         | 6.180151| 0.584817|27.954963
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.398056 and badp,
  | 0.679720.
========================================================================
 9| 9.165228|28.005567| 7.807343|         |27.058262|28.011423| 5.733149
  |         | 5.940338|         | 6.278690| 0.156334|27.930328
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Grace Note, 0.394821 and badp,
  | 0.671179.
========================================================================
10| 9.165228|28.530213| 8.412522|         |29.058262|28.417606|         
  |         | 5.940338|         | 8.475831| 3.862952|27.381043
  |---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating FallenAngelEyes and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated. Candidate Juan Manuel has reached
  | the threshold and is elected.
```

> ### Winners are Grace Note, badp, and Juan Manuel.

[image]

---

### Historical note

For better or worse, Powerlord has, months later, decided to delete his account with the site. While the reasons to do so are personal and it's in his right to do so, little do I know why people would feel the urge to *delete their accounts* where just not using them would suffice.

Anyway, this means that his nomination has disappeared from the election page and the election results file you can download now apparently denies Powerlord ever took place in this election. As a result, a vote that originally was `1 5 10 6 0` (1 vote for Juan Powerlord and Badp) now appears as `1 5 0 6 0` (1 vote for Juan, nobody and Badp).

The end results don't change as he didn't get a whole lot of votes and it's overkill to make a feature request for better handling of *deleted moderation candidates*, something that's happened once in 1.5 years. I have thus reuploaded the original ballot file for your fact checking pleasure.

#### [Download the original ballot file.](http://anyhub.net/file/17p5-gaming-stackexchange-com-2011-election-results.blt)

<sub>Okay, I'll admit I cheated. That's *not* precisely the original version; the original version had all 12 candidates at the end, including the two who didn't make it to the actual election phase. I had removed those two from the ballot file for my own processing pleasure (see everything above the historical notice). The change is however purely cosmetic and Powerlord's votes are correctly shown there.</sub>

Comment: Yes, the runner-up is Ivo Flipse.

Comment: Welcome @badp, good luck! You can now threaten people to ban them when they disagree with you!

Comment: Congratulation the Winners, I wish you an happy duty!